# Can I use ‘obwohl’ after ‘dass’

Tags: conjunction, subordinate-clause

Can I use *obwohl* after *dass* in the following sentence?

> Ich finde besonders interessant an dieser Statistik, **dass obwohl** Deutsch die am meisten gesprochene Sprache in Europa ist, Englisch die am meisten gesprochene Fremdsprache ist.

Comment: Tell us why you don't think it would be right.

Comment: It sounds good to me I just wanted to ask someone who speaks the language better than me

Comment: It is correct, but you need to insert a comma between "dass" and "obwohl", since the interjection "obwohl die Deutsch am meisten gesprochen Sprache in Europa ist" is a subclause.

Comment: @Jan Die Frage stand, wie man deutlich sehen konnte, im Titel. (editiert)

Comment: @Uwe Der Titel ist ein Titel und kein Bestandteil der Frage …

Comment: @Jan: …sondern der letzten?

Comment: Good grammar, poor style. And, as jonathan.scholbach already pointed out, you need a comma between *dass* and *obwohl*. The comma is required by the formal grammatical rules that control German commas, but in this case it also reflects a pause in speech that is required to make the structure of this overcomplicated sentence transparent.

Answer (score 6):

The structure of the sentence becomes more obvious if the "obwohl" part is moved to the end:

> Ich finde besonders interessant an dieser Statistik, **dass** Englisch die am meisten gesprochene Fremdsprache ist, **obwohl** Deutsch die am meisten gesprochene Sprache in Europa ist.

That is, the "obwohl" clause is a subclause of the "dass" clause, which is a subclause of the main clause.

You can move the "obwohl" clause from final position to middle position, but you need to enclose it within commas:

> Ich finde besonders interessant an dieser Statistik, **dass**, **obwohl** Deutsch die am meisten gesprochene Sprache in Europa ist, Englisch die am meisten gesprochene Fremdsprache ist.

In fact, you could also move it *after* the subject of the "dass" clause:

> Ich finde besonders interessant an dieser Statistik, **dass** Englisch, **obwohl** Deutsch die am meisten gesprochene Sprache in Europa ist,  die am meisten gesprochene Fremdsprache ist.

(Admittedly, the last sentence sounds a bit confusing, but grammatically, it's legal.)

Answer (score 1):

No, this sentence is grammatically wrong. The part beginning with "obwohl" is a subclause. It can easily be corrected by putting a comma in between "dass" and "obwohl":

> Ich finde besonders interessant an dieser Statistik, dass, obwohl Deutsch die am meisten gesprochene Sprache in Europa ist, Englisch die am meisten gesprochene Fremdsprache ist.

Comment: The sentence is not *grammatically* wrong; if anything, it is punctuationally wrong.

Comment: @Jan The missing comma is not just punctuation like semicolon instead of fullstop, it really leads the grammar astray beacuse "dass obwohl" is syntactically incorrect, and syntax is grammar. It is really inappropriate that you downvote my answer